# How do I check if my router/modem combo is on bridge mode?

Tags: networking, router, modem, bridge

So I want to use my own router to handle my LAN, so to avoid double NAT I call my ISP to request "Bridge Mode" (since the PPPoE dial should be done with their modem/router combo) and they call me today and told me the modem/router they gave me has been set to "Bridge Mode".

So my question is, if I connect my PC directly and use `ifconfig` or `ipconfig`, I should be getting WAN IP right?

Any help will be appreciated.
Apologize for bad english

Comment: "*So my question is, if I connect my PC directly and use ifconfig or ipconfig, I should be getting WAN IP right?*" Depends on the ISP. AT&T U-Verse, for example, does 1-to-1 NAT in bridge mode so you still get a LAN IP.

Comment: Ohh i see, so is there any other way to check to make sure I'm not on double NAT?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid double NAT if the first NAT is 1-to-1? What difference does it make? Why not check if ports pass through without special configuration? (You will need to test from outside your LAN.)

Comment: Apologize for noob question, but I thought double NAT is bad? And I always get NAT 3 (closed NAT) on my PS4 if I connect it via 2nd router, if I connect it via 1st router, then it will get NAT 2 (behind router), if I connect it directly to modem, then it will get NAT 1 (open NAT). The reason I'm avoiding double NAT is I want to use a 2nd router and not getting NAT 3 on my PS4. I hope that make sense.

Comment: 1-to-1 NAT only changes the destination IP address. It is otherwise invisible. You can detect 1-to-1 NAT because it behaves as if all ports are forwarded and, of course, can only NAT to a single destination.